# reCAPTCHA Example Needed

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I want to implement reCAPTCHA 2 on my form in the same way as this demo from Google:

[Google reCAPTCHA demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo)

but I can't find the source code. As with this demo, I don't want to submit the form and do the verification check via POST parameter as then I have to figure out how to navigate the user back to the form page; rather, I want to prevent submit until the user has clicked the 'I'm not a robot' checkbox successfully. I've gone over the Google documentation and searched the web for examples but haven't been able to figure this out - any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
The examples in the comments appear to be reCAPTCHA v1 examples, although I specifically asked for v2. I don't think you need to include a php library with v2, and what I'm really looking for is a way to ensure the user has answered the reCAPTCHA challenge before it will submit (I already have a onsubmit JS function to validate other inputs), NOT whether it validates (I'm doing that on the server php file).
As I mentioned in my original post, I have searched for an answer but have not been able to find one that replicates Google's demo that I linked to.

**Edit 2**
I was able to implement a client-side check on whether the user had completed the reCAPTCHA widget with this JavaScript on my HTML page:

```
<body>
    <form id="entryForm" name="entryForm" method="post" action="php/formSubmit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

...
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
            // User has to check reCAPTCHA
            if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                alert("Please complete the I'm-not-a-robot widget before submitting your entry.");
                //document.forms["entryForm"]["acceptAgrmt"].focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look : https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-recaptcha

Comment: Use google before posting a question. Here is an example from google https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php

Comment: I did Google (as I stated in my post) but I couldn’t find any examples for reCAPTCHA 2. The GitHub example in the comments looks like it’s for reCAPTCHA 1 which is being deprecated soon.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? As I said in my post, I did search for examples but I am specifically looking for reCAPTCHA 2 examples that prevent the user from submitting until they successfully answer the 'I am not a robot' question. Can no one help?

Comment: @RossW, I'd guess because you didn't provide any examples of what you've tried. Stack Overflow doesn't respond well to that, typically.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
<form id="entryForm" name="entryForm" method="post" action="php/formSubmit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

.
.
.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        // User has to check reCAPTCHA
        if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
            alert("Please complete the I'm-not-a-robot widget before submitting your entry.");
            //document.forms["entryForm"]["acceptAgrmt"].focus();
            return false;
        }
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

This is custom google reCAPTCHA Example done by js and HTML/CSS.    [Check with fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ram2210/tzo2jsx6/)

```js
jQuery('#save_default_color').on('change',function(){

 if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
    jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);
   jQuery('.box_layer').addClass('hide_border');
  jQuery('.circle_1').addClass('show_cir_1');
 setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('.circle_2').addClass('show_cir_2');
  },700);
 setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('.load_cir').addClass('show_load_cir');
  },1500);
  setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery('.circle_1').addClass('show_cir_1_hide');
    },2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
     complete();
    },5000);
}

});

function complete(){
  $(".complete_save").toggleClass("drawn");
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('.load_cir').removeClass('show_load_cir');
  },200);
  
}
```

```css
input#save_default_color {
    display: none;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0e0e0e;
}
.set_as_default_color {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
p.lbl_text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
.set_as_default_color label {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
        transform: scale(1.5);
}


.box_layer {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    border-radius: 15%;
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(.8);
}
.box_layer.hide_border {
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: center;
}
.circle_1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: center center;
    border: 6px solid rgba(61, 182, 228, 0.68);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:rgba(61, 182, 228, 0.50);
}
.circle_1.show_cir_1 {
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(.9);
    opacity: .3;
}
.circle_1.show_cir_1.show_cir_1_hide{
opacity:0;  
}
.circle_2{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: center center;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}
.circle_2.show_cir_2{
    transition: all .7s;
    transform: scale(.5);
}
.load_cir {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(.8);
    transform-origin: center center;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.load_cir.show_load_cir{
  opacity:1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
svg.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  x: 0px;
  y: 0px;
  viewBox: 0 0 40 40;
}
svg.spinner circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #4389f2;
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 110.6;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 20px 20px 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 20px 20px 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 20px 20px 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 20px 20px 0;
  transform-origin: 20px 20px 0;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 110.6;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(540deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 110.6;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(540deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 110.6;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: rotate(540deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 110.6;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
}
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(540deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 110.6;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
    stroke-dashoffset: 26.4;
  }
}


p.ajax_complate {
    background-color: #3e13ea;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}



.tick{
    stroke-dasharray: 50;
    stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
}
.drawn svg .path{
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.complete_save {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    top: -8px;
    left: -2px;
}
.complete_save svg {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    x: 0px;
    y: 0px;
    viewBox: 0 0 40 40;
}
```

```html
<div class="set_as_default_color">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="save_default_colors" id="save_default_color">
<div class="box_layer"></div>
<div class="circle_1"></div>
<div class="circle_2"></div>
<div class="load_cir">
<svg class="spinner">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="15"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="complete_save">
<svg>
<polyline class="tick path" style="fill:none;stroke:green;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="
 11.6,20 15.9,24.2 26.4,13.8 "/>
</svg>
</div>
</label>
<p class="lbl_text">i am not a robot</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```